# Get coordinate on click Angular Mapbox

Tags: angular, mapbox

I'm trying to get the coordinates when I click my map in Angular, but the event **return undefined**.
This is my code

HTML

```
<div id="map" (click)="getCoords($event)"></div>
```

TS

```
  getCoords(e){ 
      console.log(e.lngLat); // undefined
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapbox mouse pointer coordinates are part of the arguments param of every [**`MapMouseEvent`**](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#mapmouseevent) event. You only have to declare the event listener through the `Evented` sintax. Here you have the simplest snippet to capture:

```
// The `click` event is an example of a `MapMouseEvent`.
// Set up an event listener on the map.
map.on('click', function(e) {
    // The event object (e) contains information like the
    // coordinates of the point on the map that was clicked.
    console.log('A click event has occurred at ' + e.lngLat);
});
```

Comment: I have to  put this in the getCoords(e) function but I works!

Comment: Glad it was helpful... Indeed you can put this code directly within the `map.on('load', ...)` or `map.on('style.load', ...)` methods